# set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, gdb, valgrind

I'm writing a program that takes 2 command line arguments: `a` and `b` respectively.

Everything is good as long as `a <= 17.5`

As soon as `a > 17.5` the program throws the following error:

incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed

I've narrowed down the problem down to the following piece of code:

```
for(int a=0; a < viBrickWall.size(); a++) {
    vector<int64_t> viTmp(iK-i);
    fill(viTmp.begin(),viTmp.end(),2);

    for(int b = 0; b < viBrickWall[a].size(); b++) {
         viTmp[viBrickWall[a][b]] = 3;
    }

    viResult.push_back(viTmp);
    viTmp.clear();
}
```

Removing the latter piece of code, gets rid of the error.

I'm also using valgrind to debug the memory, but I haven't been able to find any solution.

Here it is a copy of valgrind's report:

[Report hosted in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ZNwc0mh9)

**EDIT**

I compiled the program with debugging flags:

`g++ -g -O0 -fno-inline program.cpp`

and ran it with valgrind as follows:

` valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --dsymutil=yes ./a.out 48 10 ``

I noticed the following line:

```
 ==15318== Invalid write of size 8
 ==15318==    at 0x100001719: iTileBricks(int) (test.cpp:74)
 ==15318==    by 0x100001D7D: main (test.cpp:40)
```

Line 74 is:

`viTmp[viBrickWall[a][b]] = 3;`

and Line 40 is:

`viBrickWall = iTileBricks(iPanelWidth);`

Comment: You need to compile with debug information to get useful `valgrind` output.

Comment: Hi david, thank you for the tip. 
I updated the post, and I narrowed down the problem even further. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Lines 13-19 of the `valgrind` output show the problem. It may help to add `assert` (or print) statements to those lines of code to catch the problem.

Comment: `viTmp[viBrickWall[a][b]] = 3;` Add a ton of `assert`s before the line. Make sure `a` is in range and `b` is in range. Then make sure `viBrickWall[a][b]` is in range.

Comment: That was the problem! 
I haven't fixed it yet, but a, and b are getting out of range. 
assert s will definitely help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're causing an invalid write to heap memory with this line:

`viTmp[viBrickWall[a][b]] = 3;`

this implies that `viBrickWall[a][b]` is indexing outside of `viTmp` at that time. Add

```
int i = viBrickWall[a][b];
assert(0 <= i && i < viTmp.size());
```

before the store to `viTmp[i] = 3`.

HINT: maybe increasing the size of viTmp by one would fix it:

```
-vector<int64_t> viTmp(iK-i);
+vector<int64_t> viTmp(iK - i + 1);
```

I don't know the content of `viBrickWall` so this is just an educated guess from the Valgrind output.

I'm not sure if you're using GNU `libstdc++` or `libc++` on Mac OSX. If you're using `libstdc++` or have a Linux box handy, declare `viTmp` to be a `std::__debug::vector` would catch this problem quickly.

Comment: scott thanks a lot for your insight. 
I fixed the problem before looking at your answer, but you were right :)
Thanks a lot.